# Error in manifest file during signed apk creation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

There is no error in my problem while compiling it and it runs good in device.When i am trying to create an signed apk it shows error in manifest.xml file which is shown below

```
E:\updated one\Wed Studio\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:842: Error: The <activity> element must be a direct child of the <application> element [WrongManifestParent]
            <activity
            ^
E:\updated one\Wed Studio\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml:845: Error: The <activity> element must be a direct child of the <application> element [WrongManifestParent]
            <activity
            ^

   Explanation for issues of type "WrongManifestParent":
   The <uses-library> element should be defined as a direct child of the
   <application> tag, not the <manifest> tag or an <activity> tag. Similarly,
   a <uses-sdk> tag much be declared at the root level, and so on. This check
   looks for incorrect declaration locations in the manifest, and complains if
   an element is found in the wrong place.
```

Tell me the possible solution to solve this issue friends
Thank you in advance.

manifest.xml

```
    <!-- android:installLocation="preferExternal" -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <!--
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
 <application
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:icon="@drawable/wedicon"
        android:label="iWedplanner"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Frontpage"
            android:label="iWedPlanner" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
<activity
            android:name=".Fsearch"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fsearch" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Rsvp_listeng"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rsvp_listeng" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Rsvp_guestnores"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rsvp_guestnores" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Engagement_edit"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_engagement_edit" />
        <activity android:name=".Reception_edit" />
        <activity android:name=".Reception_Tabledetail" />
        <activity android:name=".Wedding_edit" />
        <activity android:name=".Wedding_Tabledetail" />
   </application>
 <activity android:name=".Countdownsongplay" />
        <activity android:name=".Wedtime" />
        <activity android:name=".Unitcal" />
        <activity android:name=".Heart" />
        <activity android:name=".Kisses" />
        <activity android:name=".Phrase" />
        <activity android:name=".Remainshow" />
        <activity android:name=".ColorPickerActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Logout" />
        <activity
            android:name="jim.h.common.android.zxinglib.CaptureActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
        <activity android:name=".Hair" />
        <activity android:name=".Hair1" />
        <activity android:name=".Inapp" />
        <activity
            android:name=".websiteview"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_websiteview" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CountdownSlideshow"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_countdown_slideshow" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InappCountdown"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_inapp_countdown" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".InappSeating"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_inapp_seating" >
        </activity>

</manifest>
```

Comment: its to large impossible to post entire manifest file i have posted the codings which shows errors make read on it

Answer (score 3):

The error says it loud and clear. Your activities declaration is outside application tag. It should look like this:

```
    <application
    android:name=".MyApplication">

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
      ....
    </activity>

</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

just cut your `</application>` and paste it to before `</manifest>`.

Comment: I did what u have said.It shows error in application like.."Element application must be declared"

Comment: Its very large stack overflow will won't allow to post that much large files.can i send u by mail

Comment: check your mail DroidDev

Comment: ping u later taking luch now

Comment: Its ok.Take your time